# Get the root child record using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Based on the series record below how to get the last child record (ST) given the fact of their Position hierarchy.

**Legend**

```
PM (Project Manager) - is the highest role position
PS (Project Supervisor) - is the down-line of PM
ST (Staff) - is the down-line of PS and the lowest role position
```

**DATA**

```
ID   Name           RoleCode    RoleDescription       ReportingtoID 
1    Will Smith       PM        Project Manager        NULL
2    Zoey Nathan      PM        Project Manager        NULL
3    Louise Norton    PS        Project Supervisor     1
4    Cynthia Villaz   PS        Project Supervisor     1
5    Ronald Trimp     PS        Project Supervisor     2
6    Lebron James     ST        Staff                  3
7    Raymond Trimp    ST        Staff                  4
8    Kevin Garn       ST        Staff                  3
9    Kobe Spars       ST        Staff                  5
10   Paul Lee         ST        Staff                  3
11   Mark Pingris     ST        Staff                  4
12   Elton Horn       ST        Staff                  1
13   Shayne Wyn       ST        Staff                  1
```

**Example 1**

If we going to fetch the down-line of **Zoey Nathan (PM)** no record will be reflected since this person has no down-line.

If we are going to fetch the child root of **Will Smith (PM)** the result should be below:

*Explanation below: **Will Smith** have two down-line namely **Louise Norton** and **Cynthia Villaz** and both of them have also different down-line which are all STAFF position. Since the STAFF is the lowest hierarchy then all of them should be display. Also, there is an instance that the STAFF is also directly reporting to Project Manager, that's why the **Elton Horn** and **Shayne Wyn** are both inlcuded on the results.*

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
ID   Name           RoleCode    RoleDescription       ReportingtoID 
6    Lebron James     ST        Staff                  3
7    Raymond Trimp    ST        Staff                  4
8    Kevin Garn       ST        Staff                  3
10   Paul Lee         ST        Staff                  3
11   Mark Pingris     ST        Staff                  4
12   Elton Horn       ST        Staff                  1
13   Shayne Wyn       ST        Staff                  1
```

**Example 2**

If we are going to fetch the child root of **Cynthia Villaz (PS)** the result should be below:

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
ID   Name           RoleCode    RoleDescription       ReportingtoID 
7    Raymond Trimp    ST        Staff                  4
11   Mark Pingris     ST        Staff                  4
```

**Example 3**

If we are going to fetch the child root of **Ronald Trimp  (PS)** the result should be below:

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
ID   Name           RoleCode    RoleDescription       ReportingtoID 
9    Kobe Spars       ST        Staff                  5
```

**Example 4**

If we are going to fetch the child root of **Raymond Trimp  (ST)** the result should be below:

*Since ST is the lowest rank then there should be no record will be display.*

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
ID   Name           RoleCode    RoleDescription       ReportingtoID 
                       No Record Found
```

I am using SQL Server 2016?  Need help please. Can someone do the codes for me then I will improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,Name varchar(50),RoleCode varchar(25),RoleDescription varchar(50),ReportingtoID  int)
Insert into @YourTable values 
(1   ,'Will Smith'       ,'PM'        ,'Project Manager'        ,NULL),
(2   ,'Zoey Nathan'      ,'PM'        ,'Project Manager'        ,NULL),
(3   ,'Louise Norton'    ,'PS'        ,'Project Supervisor'     ,1),
(4   ,'Cynthia Villaz'   ,'PS'        ,'Project Supervisor'     ,1),
(5   ,'Ronald Trimp'     ,'PS'        ,'Project Supervisor'     ,2),
(6   ,'Lebron James'     ,'ST'        ,'Staff'                  ,3),
(7   ,'Raymond Trimp'    ,'ST'        ,'Staff'                  ,4),
(8   ,'Kevin Garn'       ,'ST'        ,'Staff'                  ,3),
(9   ,'Kobe Spars'       ,'ST'        ,'Staff'                  ,5),
(10  ,'Paul Lee'         ,'ST'        ,'Staff'                  ,3),
(11  ,'Mark Pingris'     ,'ST'        ,'Staff'                  ,4),
(12  ,'Elton Horn'       ,'ST'        ,'Staff'                  ,1),
(13  ,'Shayne Wyn'       ,'ST'        ,'Staff'                  ,1)

Declare @Top  int         = null      --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 1 for Will Smith 
Declare @Leaf bit         = 0         --<<  Toggle Leaf Only
Declare @Nest varchar(25) = '|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteP as (
      Select Seq  = cast(10000+Row_Number() over (Order by Name) as varchar(500))
            ,ID
            ,ReportingtoID 
            ,Lvl=1
            ,Name
            ,RoleCode 
      From   @YourTable 
      Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(ReportingtoID ,-1) else ID end
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(concat(p.Seq,'.',10000+Row_Number() over (Order by r.Name)) as varchar(500))
            ,r.ID
            ,r.ReportingtoID 
            ,p.Lvl+1
            ,r.Name
            ,r.RoleCode  
      From   @YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.ReportingtoID  = p.ID)
     ,cteR1 as (Select *,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteP)
     ,cteR2 as (Select A.ID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.ID )
Select A.R1  
      ,B.R2
      ,A.ID
      ,A.ReportingtoID 
      ,A.Lvl
      ,Name = case when @Leaf = 1 then '' else Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) end + A.Name
      ,A.RoleCode
 From  cteR1 A
 Join  cteR2 B on A.ID=B.ID
 Where A.R1 = case when @Leaf=1 then B.R2 else A.R1 end
 Order by case when @Leaf=1 then A.ID else A.R1 end
```

**When @Top = 1 and @Leaf = 1 You'll get the following**

[image]

**When @Top = 1 and @Leaf = 0 You'll get the Nested Hierarchy**

[image]

**When @Top = NULL and @Leaf = 0 You'll get the FULL Hierarchy**

[image]

Comment: @user1852837 thanks for the grin.  I'm sure my wife would disagree. :)